# jQuery $.get() not working in Drupal 6

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

So I am running into this problem. I am trying to use $.get() to interact with a REST application within Drupal 6.16, which uses jQuery 1.2.6

I have a test page on the desktop where I run the following code, and it successfully runs the alert.

```
  url = 'http://api.twitter.com/1/help/test.xml';
  $.get(url, function(){alert("WORKING!!");}, 'xml');
```

When I try to run it within Drupal, however, the alert is never reached. For some reason, the function never gets triggered.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wow... 1.2.6 is old enough to be in a museum. Surprising Drupal don't keep it up to date!

Comment: Use Firefox with Firebug and look at the console for any JS errors.

Comment: I am using Firefox with Firebug, and there are no errors. And yes, it is an old version. It seems that they have code tied to it, so that is why they don't update it. In any case, I tested the old jquery in my test page, and it worked correctly.

Comment: There is a contrib module for keeping up actively with jQuery releases, called jquery_update (http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I have to say to this is:

[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

> In a nutshell, the policy permits
>   scripts running on pages originating
>   from the same site to access each
>   other's methods and properties with no
>   specific restrictions, but prevents
>   access to most methods and properties
>   across pages on different sites.

And that's exactly what you are trying to do. Making a ajax-request to a different domain then where the script is located. Which doesn't work because the same origin policy prohibits cross-domain-requests.

Check if the offer a jsonp api and read the [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) documentation how to use/make jsonp cross-domain-requests. Now obviously the alert is never reached as the call doesn't succeed and jQuery thus doesn't call the success-callback you specified.

Comment: Thanks, jitter! I forgot about this policy. :) Now I can proceed from here :)